# How to download files matching a particular pattern from ftp command line

Tags: command-line, bash, ftp, regex

I am accessing ftp through command line and trying to delete all the files matching particular pattern. But seems it does literal match than regex match.

Can somebody suggest anyway that we can do pattern match in ftp command line client?

```
ftp> get *.tgz
200 PORT command successful.
550 The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Comment: What FTP client are you using, and what command are you trying that doesn't work? You say you're trying to delete, but you're doing get?

Comment: Its command line client, after get I tried del, but again same error ftp> del *.tgz
550 The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're simply using commands designed for single files, but using wildcards.

Try the commands:

```
mget *.tgz
mdel *.tgz
```